# How to avoid RichTextBox grows to right

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a problem that is driving me crazy, I am working on a project in WPF and I am creating a view.

I was designing a window which contains a "More Options" section, I had even been able to make this section show or hide. This section contained a tabControl which contained a TextBox as bellow:

```
<TabControl Margin="10,156,12,39" Name="moreTabControl" Grid.Column="1">
    <TabItem >
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Margin="6,6,8,28" Name="myTextBox"  />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

So, in the code behind what I do to show or hide the "More Section" is as following:

```
public partial class FilterView : System.Windows.Window
{
    .....
    // Window's height when "more" option are showed
    private const int ShowMoreHeight = 386;

    /// Window's height when "more" option are hidden
    private const int ShowLessHeight = 186;

    private bool showMore = false;

    private void moreButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        showMore = !showMore;
        ResizeWindow();
    }

     private void ResizeWindow()
    {
        if (showMore)
        {
            moreTabControl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            moreButton.Content = "<< Less";
            MinHeight = ShowMoreHeight;
            Height = ShowMoreHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            moreTabControl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            moreButton.Content = "More >>";
            MinHeight = ShowLessHeight;
            Height = ShowLessHeight;
        }
    }
......
.....
}
```

Everything went well until I needed to change the TextBox for a RichTextBox :(, when I run the program and press the "MoreButton" the "more" section is showed as expected but the container window grows a lot to the right!

And I only changed this: `<TextBox Margin="6,6,8,28" Name="myTextBox" />` for this: `<RichTextBox Margin="6,6,8,28" Name="myRichTextBox"  />`

Does anyone know what is happening??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if i understand your question, you are saying when the MoreButton is pressed the window grows in height like expected but also grows in width which you dont want?

Comment: @Jay Exactly!!! It does happen!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem:

Turns out that in my XAML code, my Window had a property called `SizeToContent` set to `"WidthAndHeight"`, so I changed it to `"Manual"` and established a value for `Width` and `Height` manually.

Hope this helps some else who is experiencing somethig similar.